# ¿Cómo poder modelar las elecciones de combo de comida, sin caer en dependencias circulares y claves foráneas nulas?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Me encuentro diseñando un modelo para pedidos de restaurantes usando `SQL server`, en el cual contemplo también el diseño de la carta. Mi problema básico, es que tengo un modelado en donde relaciono `Promociones`, y el usuario puede elegir que plato escoger (si hay mas de uno para elegir) en cada etapa de la `promoción` (por ejemplo, uno para la entrada, otro para el plato fuerte y otro para postre). A su vez, el cliente puede en un mismo pedido, o un pedido realizado sin promociones, elegir `Items` (platos o bebidas) para el pedido, los cuales están relacionados con una tabla intermedia (`ItemAttributeXItem` ), y esta otra tabla que es `attribute` (porque quiero que en el menú, se agrupen los mismos `ítems`, y pueda desplegar un combo con las variantes, y asi, no tener 5 `items` de coca cola, cuando lo único que cambia son los mililitros, o tenes una misma pizza, en donde lo único que cambia es si es media o entera, pero en si es lo mismo, asi de esta forma saco la redundancia, y evito tener registros de lo mismo, obteniendo una carta mas pequeña para el usuario). Ligado a esta idea, cada `ítem` puede tener `Ítems` extras, donde el cliente puede ver y elegir en la carta, con que desea acompañar una carne, o que salsa agregarle a una pasta (los cuales pueden repetirse para mas de un plato). Las relaciones de todo esto quedaría de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es, que de esta manera, no se como guardar estas posibles elecciones en un `OrderDetail`, sin caer en relaciones circulares y claves foráneas nulas entre `OderDetail` con `ItemAttributeXItemXStageXPromotion` (cuando es el ítem elegido para una o mas etapas dentro de una promoción), `ItemAttributeXItem` (cuando elije un plato/bebida individual) e `ExtraIngredientXItem` (cuando quiero saber cual agregado eligió para el plato puntual, si es que este tenia esa opción). ¿Mi diseño esta mal planteado? ¿O lo que tendría que cambiar es algo relacionado a la lógica de mi `orderdetail`? Estuve bastante tiempo armándolo, y es el único que encontré que me cumple con lo que necesito, sacando los problemas que me presenta con lo planteado mas arriba. Se que tiene muchas mas cosas que la clásica relación de pedido e ítem, pero la idea es poder brindar un menú customizable, robusto y adaptable a cualquier restaurante, además de como mencione arriba, dejar de tener la redundancia del mismo plato, en donde solo cambia los ml o la porción (además  de que sin, por ejemplo, `extraingredient`, se complicaria llevar el stock de lo que se gasto de la materia prima para elaborar ese agregado puntual).
Resalto, que en todas las relaciones, usando estas tablas intermedias, tendria 2 con 2 columnas como clave principal, e `ItemAttributeXItemXStageXPromotion` que tiene 4, para poder modelar que `ItemAttributeXItem` se eligió, para que `Stage` de una determinada `promotion`.

Comment: Por favor, especifica el motor de SQL que usas así podemos darte una respuesta precisa.

Comment: Ahora lo especifico. No lo coloque en la pregunta, porque lo considere que era una cuestión de diseño indiferente al motor de SQL.